# Is "denied-entry" a synonym of "denial-of-entry"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[denied-entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denied-entry) has 1 question and [denial-of-entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-entry) has more. [denied-entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denied-entry) has a long description though but it seems it's just a duplicate. Should they be synonyms?

Comment: Yes they should be synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. I deleted [denied-entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denied-entry), replaced it with [denial-of-entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-entry), and made the first a synonym of the second. Thank you for bringing this up. Keep up the good work.